# Observation on sequence A007018

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

Define $n$th term $a(n)=a(n-1)^2+a(n-1)$ and $a(0)=1$ [sequence a(n)](https://oeis.org/A007018)

$a(n)=1,2,6,42,1806,3263442,...$

Define $S(x,y)=1^y+2^y+3^y+...+x^y$

> Can it be shown that
>
> For all $k\le n$
> $$S(a(k),a(n-1))\equiv1\pmod{a(k)}$$

For example let $n=2$

$a(0)=1,\ \ a(1)=a(n-1)=2,\ \ a(2)=a(n)=6$

$$\begin{split} S(1,2)&=1&\equiv 1\pmod1\\ S(2,2)&=5&\equiv1\pmod2\\S(6,2)&=91&\equiv1\pmod6\end{split}$$

I checked $n$ upto $4$

Comment: Do you have any reason to expect this to be true?

Comment: @MattSamuel given $2y$ for $S(x,2y)\equiv 1\pmod{x}$  then every $x$ belongs to given sequence A007018. Hence sequence support given claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not work for $n=5$ and $k=5$, and gives $S(a(5),a(4))= 1807 \mod a(5)$

Strange enough $1807 = a(4)+1$, so it could be that there is some sort of connection.

Comment: Thanks for your time to go through it. You should check out similar question related to gigua number https://mathoverflow.net/q/350294/149083